# Triggering another node-red using webhooks

Tags: node-red

I'm currently playing around with node-red, i'm trying to "trigger" another node red using webhooks.

[image: Node-red (server-pC)]

[image: Rpi [client node red]]

photo one is configure as the server.
the next photo is configure as the client  the one will be trigger.
but it ended up not working.

Comment: You are going to need to supply a lot more than "it's not working" and a picture of some nodes

Comment: more likely i'm playing on that features. Ending up not triggering it

Comment: Edit the question to include a lot more detail (e.g. how the http-request node is configured and the hostnames)